Amount of sets in covering needed for a submanifold to get surface coordinates is diffeo-invariant?
Suppose two submanifolds $M_1, M_2$ (say of $\mathbb{R}^3$) are given by $F_1(x)=0,F_2(x)=0$ respectively. Then if these are diffeomorphic to each other, there is a map $\phi : M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ (a question here: This needs to be a map for every coordinate chart? Or can one define it on the whole manifold globally? It should be given globally, but its form may change depending on which coordinates you use to represent the map one $M_1,M_2$, right?), such that if $x_1\in M_1$ then $\phi(x_2)\in M_2$ for all $x_1$. And conversly, all $x_2$ can be determined that way.
So if $M_1$ is e.g. $S_1$, the circle, then we need two open sets on which we define surface coordinates. Does this mean every curve diffeo to the circle also only requires two surface charts, regardless of how crooked and winded it might be?

Embarrassingly enough, I figured out the answer right after I posted the question. Should I delete this? At least I think you can just compose the diffeo with the chart of the circle to get another chart on the other mnfld. And if you do this for every chart, you get an smooth atlas, since diffeo are bijective in particular
